# Simple browser activity for use inside app

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there an equivalent of [SVWebViewController](https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController) for Android?

I just want a simple browser activity that has the basic forward/back buttons built in but for Android. I know it isn't a huge deal to build myself, but I figured I would check first.

I can't simply use an `Intent` to open the URL in the default browser because I need to show pages that require the user to login and I have no control over the server.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't simply use an Intent to open the URL in the default browser
>   because I need to show pages that require the user to login and I have
>   no control over the server.

=> In that case, you can use [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) with [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) in Android.

For example:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
 });

 webview.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear. The user is already logged in and I simply want to display a page. But it would seem the answer is no, I have to implement the "browser" part of the WebView myself?

Comment: @AlecGorge I am not sure what you are saying exactly but if you want to show web pages based on navigation user do then WebViewClient is the solution in Android.

Comment: I realize that, I was asking if there was a prebuilt solution that already had the buttons and other details already wired up so that all you had to do was start the activity with a URL.